# Using ffplay or ffmpeg how can I get a pixel's rgb value in a frame

Tags: c++, video, ffmpeg, decode

I would like to extract a pixel's rgb value in every frame that is decoded using ffmpeg. I looked into ffplay source code

```
get_video_frame
video_refresh
queue_picture
```

I tried the above three methods to hook on to the frame but I do not understand how to get a pixel's rgb value. Could anyone kindly give some pointer into this

Comment: Video do not operate on RGB, it uses YCbCr (normally subsampled 4:2:0, use wikipedia if you don't understand) Then just do `ffmpeg -i file.264 out.yuv` to get the reconstructed buffer. In that you will have all the pixelvalues directly as uint8.

Comment: I want the pixel values to be fed to an external process so I can't dump them to a file and read them externally. So the idea is when I play a video, I want to open a socket and send the pixel values

Comment: As I said. ffmpeg delivers YCbCr 4:2:0 data. If you need RGB that data needs to be converted to RGB using a transform-matrixes as defined in Rec.601 or Rec.709. The function `avcodec_decode_video2` returns a YCbCr decoded buffer. ffmpeg could probably do the conversion as well but I never work with RGB-data so I don't know how

Comment: Not necessarily true. avcodec_decode_video2 gives you the pixel data in whatever format the codec encoded it. YCbCr 4:2:0 is probably the most common format, but it could be RGB, YUV444, etc. You need to check pix_fmt in AVCodec. From there you can extract pixel data from the AVFrame struct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
http://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=805
```

Thats the source and this is the conversion source I used and it works as expected. Hope this helps someone

```
ColorRGB GetRGBPixel(const AVFrame& frame, int x, int y)
{
    // Y component
    const unsigned char y = frame.data[0][frame.linesize[0]*y + x];

    // U, V components 
    x /= 2;
    y /= 2;
    const unsigned char u = frame.data[1][frame.linesize[1]*y + x];
    const unsigned char v = frame.data[2][frame.linesize[2]*y + x];

    // RGB conversion
    const unsigned char r = y + 1.402*(v-128);
    const unsigned char g = y - 0.344*(u-128) - 0.714*(v-128);
    const unsigned char b = y + 1.772*(u-128);

    return ColorRGB(r, g, b);
}
```